# Regex in java to find if a String is in the format of a decimal number with a trailing zero

Tags: java, regex, string, type-conversion, substring

I am reading a list of Strings, some of which are in the form of decimals and comapring them against another. Sadly, in the first list, I find that all decimal terms aka all the strings have an extra trailing zero. Thus, my .equals() function or .contains() function does not work.

```
List 1 : 134.20, 16, abacus, 44.10, 12/2/2013, 4, 45.220
List 2 : 134.2,  16, abacus, 44.2,  12/2/2013, 4, 45.22
```

How do I add a trailing zero in List 2? Is there way to use regex or so to somehow remove the trailing zero if present?

Conversely, can I remove the trailing zero in List 1?

Comment: In your example, there is also a comma and dot difference in the last column.

Comment: An error on my part. Changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get read of all unneccessary trailing zeroes:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(\\d+\\.\\d+?)0+", "$1");
```

Examples:

```
123.456000 --> 123.456
123.000    --> 123.0
```

---

Update: In the comment you asked how to unconditionally append a zero. This is how you do it:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(\\d+\\.\\d+)", "$10");
```

Comment: That seems to work. Can do the opposite too? As in with 123.456, get 123.4560 ?

Comment: Do you always want to add a zero, or only if it doesn't already end with a zero.

Comment: Always add a zero to any decimal like number. Hence, 120.0 becimes 120.00 and 123.4 becomes 123.40.

Comment: I don't think I'll ever get a number like 120.000 or so. I'll have to buy a gun and shoot my DBA then.

Comment: str = str.replaceAll("(\\d+\\.\\d+)", "$10");

Comment: let me check this out!

Comment: I found another problem, trailing back to your suggestion. What if I want to restrict it only to two decimals. Hence, 123.2 becomes 123.20 but 123.33 remains the same?

Comment: `str = str.replaceAll("(\\d+\\.\\d\\b)","$10");` This pattern has only one digit to the right of the decimal point, and \\b is in there to make sure the digit is "at the end of the word" and isn't followed by another digit (or a letter, for that matter).  Note: I haven't tested this.  Also, if there are three or more digits to the right, it won't change it.

Comment: @gran_profaci: You really need to think about your question prior to posting it. I posted a solution to your question and a solution to your first question in the comment. You didn't even upvote my answer (nor accept it, as it does answer the original question) - that's not a big motivation to answer more and more follow up questions from the comment. Your req. with 2 decimals is still unclear: What happens to `456.789`?

Answer (score 1):

To remove trailing zeroes from decimals:

```
String zeroless = str.replaceAll("(\\b\\d+\\.[1-9]*)0+\\b", "$1");
```

To add trailing a zero where there isn't one:

```
String zeroless = str.replaceAll("(\\b\\d+\\.\\d*)[1-9]\\b", "$10");
```

An important part of this regex is the wrapping with `\\b` - a "word boundary".

---

I'm not sure how useful either of these will be. If you're try to see if a particular decimal is in a string, remove the trailing zeroes from it, then search for it in your input with *optional* trailing zeros, like this:

```
String num;  // eg 123.456
if (input.matches(".*\\b" + num.replace(".", "\\.").replaceAll("0+$", "") + "0*\\b.*")) {
    // input contains the number
}
```

Comment: It won't, the whole regex is group 1.

Comment: What if I want to add a zero to the decimal?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `String.format()` to get them all to how ever many decimal places.

```
String yourValue = "4.4";
int range = 3;
String zeros = String.format("%."+range+"f", Float.parseFloat(yourValue)); // 3 decimal places
System.out.println(zeros); // prints 4.400
```

Change range as needed for different number of decimal places needed.

Alternatively, if you are just using them to check if they are equal/greater/less then why don't you just parse the string as Double (or other suitable object) and then compare the Doubles then `"2.2" == "2.20"` anyway and you can use the already defined `equals()` and `compareTo()` for those objects

Comment: Sadly, I have different ranges of decimals that I cannot mess with. I wish I could just append one zero to the decimal strings and chill out.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using BigDecimal to compare decimal values, not Strings at all. Get rid of the regular expression, use new BigDecimal(String), set the scale you want, and then use `compareTo().`